# Strange backbone notice

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

this morning i found a curious info on my firebug console:

> Illuminations: Patching Backbone so Models and Views are enumerable

as the info says i tried to update backbone from 0.9.9 to 0.9.10, but the message still on my console...

What does it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `Illuminations` firefox plugin installed. It is just telling you what it is doing.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/illuminations-for-developers/

Comment: nice forgot about this addon :facepalm:

Comment: I don't have this add-on but I still get it. Did it get baked into Firebug recently?

Comment: @kinakuta No idea. The error message has the name of the addon in it, so I can't imagine it would end up in anything else.